# Issues with downgrading from SHA to MD5 - Postgresql / pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, unity-game-engine, md5, npgsql

I have a Unity3D project that I'm attempting to hook up to a Postgresql database, my issue now is "NpgsqlException: Exception_AuthenticationMethodNotSupported" when I try to connect to my test db.

My connection string looks like:

```
"Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password={removed};Database=test";
```

I have already altered:

postgresql.conf -

```
password_encryption = md5
```

&

pg_hba.conf -

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

All recommendations from the internet. I have attempted to restart the postgresql service after these changes were made when pgAdmin4 is disconnected from server and closed.

I am doing all of this as Unity3D doesn't support .NET framework versions required for the latest npgsql.dll files, instead I have to use a forked UnityNpgsql.dll that rids many errors I was originally having.

I'm a bit stuck, I feel as if it's still using SHA and i'm not sure how to force it not to.

Any ideas are much appreciated

Comment: password_encryption only affects passwords now getting "encrypted" for storage.  So changing the setting does nothing until the password is reset.  Until then, the password is still stored in a format which md5 can't use.